# How to allow AV Movie Player to auto-lock iPhone while playing video?

Tags: ios, video, avplayer, auto-lock

I play background video using AV Movie Player in my application. As soon as I navigate from that screen I pause that video, thus, the iPhone auto-locks after regular time interval set in the iPhone. But if I remain on that screen which plays the video, it never auto-locks itself. How do I enable the auto-lock on this screen as well?

Can I use MP movie player or any other movie player to allow auto-locking of iPhone while video is being payed?

Please provide code snippets to handle this scenario.

Comment: I don't think the iPhone can auto-lock while any video is playing.